# EF Core Update-Database throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to test making SQLite database using EF.Core. Despite all my effort to get it work, it still not working as intended and i don't know why. The Add-Migration command works ok but then when i try to Update-DataBase it throws System.NullReferenceException. Anyone has an idea why is that? Below you can see the code and the exception.

```
public class TestModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

```
private const string ConnectionString = "Data Source = AutoHome.db";

        public DbSet<TestModel> testModels { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlite(ConnectionString);
            base.OnConfiguring(options);
        }
```

> PM> Update-DataBase
>   Build started...
>   Build succeeded.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   PM>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that it is an issue with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core. I just added a reference Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and everything works right now.

OBS!!!

There is already an open ticket about this [GitHub/EF/Issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18827)

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Just wanted to add that your problems might not end there. After troubleshooting further and further I ran into this issue: SQLite does not support this migration operation ('DropColumnOperation'). For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723262 - which basically means Migrations aren't fully supported or at least compatible to MSSQL unless you tend to drop columns from time to time.